# I am having issues building android via cordova build

Tags: android, cordova

I am having issue building android app with cordova build android command on nodejs command prompt, whenever I type "cordova build" this is the error I am getting below:

```
C:\Users\lovely\Desktop\hello>cordova build

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\lovely\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

Comment: I found the solution after Googling `Cordova Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap`

Comment: @Zun   Many thanks to you, problems resolved, works like a charm.